# onmouse over php object

Tags: php, css, onmouseover

I'm trying to develop a mouse over effect for my php elements. it's a store and I'm simply tying to have a transparent div appear over the auto generated php areas. it's simply set to display block to be able to see if it will display correctly. It only appears beneath the image and the text.

html/php

```
        <div id="scoll" class="group">
            <div class="container"> 
                <div class="center_items">


             <?php
    //external pages area
    include_once('config\database.php');
    include_once('object/chair.php');
    $database = new Database();
    $conn = $database->getConnection();
    $chair = new Chair($conn);
    $stmt = $chair->readAll();
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        ?>

        <div class="product_box" >
        <div class="buy-box-shadow">
        <!--   <div class="buy-product">-->
        <a href="chair-details.php?detailsid=<?php echo $row['ID'];?>"> <img src="img/<?php echo $row['THUMB']; ?>" alt="chair_image"> </a>
        <h4><a href="movies-details.php?detailsid=<?php echo $row['ID'];?>"> <?php echo $row['chair_name'];?></a> </h4>
        <p>$<?php echo $row['PRICE'];?></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
 <!--  </div>buy product-->

                </div>
            </div>              
        </div>
```

css

```
.center_items{
    width:74%;
    margin:0 auto;  

}
.product_box{
    width:200px;
    float:left;
    margin: 4.5em 5%;
    box-shadow:0px 6px 16px #888888;
}

.product_box img{
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
}

.static-nav{
    height:200px;
    background-color:white;

}
.buy-box-shadow{
    background-color:black;
    z-index:100;
    display:block;


}
```

Comment: I would try setting a z-index on the items you want behind the div to lower, then also give all the elements with z-indexs positioning, like "position: relative;"

Answer (score 0):

div for hover needs to be at the bottom and close at the same time. You can't use background color but you can use an image.

```
.buy-box-shadow{
    opacity: .6;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding-top: 50%;
    background: transparent url('img/Untitled-2.gif');
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 100;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;


}
```